# How can a ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field $k$, and in infinitely many variables be a subring of $k[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, definition, polynomial-rings

I am trying to answer this question:

Let $k$ be a field and $k[x,y].$ Define the subring $A \subset k[x,y]$ by $A = k[x, xy, xy^2, xy^3, ...].$ Show that $A$ is not Noetherian.

**But I have the following question:**

How can a ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field $k$, and in **infinitely many variables**, in our case $A$ be a subring of $k[x,y]$ which is a ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field $k$, and in **finitely many variables** ? should not $A$ be at least a finite set? could anyone give me an example to clarify this point please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element of $A$ can be written as a finite linear combination $\sum p_\alpha X^\alpha$ of monomials $X^\alpha$ where each monomial is of the form

$$X^\alpha = (x y^{i_1})^{j_1} \cdots (x y^{i_n})^{j_n}$$

At the end, you get an element of $k[x,y]$.

The variables of $A$, namely $x, xy, \dots$ are not *independent*.

Comment: can you give me a concrete example please?

Comment: what is the importance of knowing that the variables of $A$ are not independent? how that will help me?

Comment: why $A$ can be written as a **finite** linear combination of monomials?

Comment: @Confusion An example of an element of $A$ is $x^2(xy^3)^4 + (xy^6)(xy^{21})^4=x^6y^{12} +x^5y^{90}$. Just convince yourself of what an element of $A$ is.

Comment: @Confusion This is by definition of what a [polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition_(multivariate_case)) is. What is an element of $\mathbb Q[x]$? Answer: a finite combination of the elements $1, x, x^2...$. It is the same for multivariate polynomials.

Comment: what about the answer to my second comment?

Comment: Yes, but as for monovariate, the linear combination has to be finite by definition. Refer (which is instructive) to the **definition** of multivariate polynomials. In the link I provided above for example. I shouldn't emphasize enough... refer to definitions to understand precisely what an object is!!!

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comment that you answered it ..... here is it ..... but $A$ is a polynomial in **infinite** (not independent variables as you said) variables.

Comment: [Polynomial with infinitely many variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Infinitely_many_variables). A paragraph of the link I provided above.

Comment: Is your previous comment an answer to my second comment ? the importance of the variables of $A$ being **not** linearly independent?

Comment: Does being not independent variables makes them behave as one variable?

Comment: but the element of $A$ you gave to me you did not express it as a monomial and you are saying that every element can be expressed as a monomial .... so how can you express that element as a monomial?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a notational issue:

Let $S\le R$ be (commutative) rings, and $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}\subseteq R$.
Then $S[a_1,a_2,\dots]$ simply denotes the subring generated by $S\cup A$, i.e. the smallest subring of $R$ that contains both $S$ and $A$.

Note that, however, there's a homomorphism $\varphi$ from the polynomial ring $S[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ to $R$ that maps $x_i\mapsto a_i$, and $S[a_1,a_2,\dots]$ is just the image of $\varphi$.

Comment: can you give me a concrete example please to a polynomial of $A$ and how it can be written as a polynomial in $k[x,y]?$ I am still confused.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the polynomial ring $A = k[xy^i \,|\, i \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}].$ By definition, an element of $A$ is of the form $$c_1 (xy^{i_{1,1}})^{n_{1,1}} \cdots (xy^{i_{1, \ell_1}})^{n_{1, \ell_1}} + c_2 (xy^{i_{2,1}})^{n_{2,1}} \cdots (xy^{i_{2, \ell_2}})^{n_{2, \ell_2}} + \cdots + c_k (xy^{i_{k,1}})^{n_{k,1}} \cdots (xy^{i_{k, \ell_k}})^{n_{k, \ell_k}}$$ for some scalars $c_j$ in $k,$ some distinct integers $i_{j, m} \geq 0,$ and some integers $n_{j, m} \geq 0.$ By the fourth sentence of the following [link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Ring_of_polynomials), "it is possible to speak of a ring of polynomials in an infinite set of variables if it is assumed that each individual polynomial depends only on a finite number of variables." Considering that the variables of $A$ are $x, xy, xy^2, xy^3,$ etc., it follows that a polynomial in $A$ is a finite $k$-linear combination of products of powers of the variables $x, xy, xy^2, xy^3,$ etc., and so, we arrive at a concrete description of a typical element of $A.$

Bearing this all in mind, it follows that $-x$ and $3(xy^2)^3 - \frac 1 7 (xy^9)^2$ and $(xy^2)^3 (xy^3)^2 + (xy^2)^2$ are all elements of $A.$ But as these are all polynomials in the variables $x$ and $y$ with coefficients in $k,$ these are all elements of $k[x, y],$ as well.

Ultimately, the fact that $A \subseteq k[x, y]$ follows from the fact that all of the monomial generators of $A$ belong to $k[x, y]$: $xy^i$ is a monomial in $k[x, y]$ for all integers $i \geq 0.$ Consequently, any $k$-linear combination of powers of the generators of $A$ belongs to $k[x, y]$ so that $A \subseteq k[x, y].$

We may now use the [subring test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring#Subring_test) to prove that $A \subseteq k[x, y]$ as rings. By the previous paragraph, we have that $A \subseteq k[x, y].$ Considering that $1 = 1x^0$ is an element of $A,$ it follows that $A$ contains the multiplicative identity of $k[x, y].$ Clearly, $A$ is closed under subtraction: the difference of two polynomials in $A$ is again a polynomial in $A,$ as it is a $k$-linear combination of products of powers of the generators of $A.$ Last, by the distributive property of $A$ (indeed, this holds because $A$ is by definition a ring), any product of elements in $A$ is itself another element of $A$ because the product $(xy^i)^{n_i} (xy^j)^{n_j}$ of any powers of any two monomial generators of $A$ is itself a polynomial in $A.$ By the subring test, therefore, we conclude that $A$ is a subring of $k[x, y].$

Comment: I guess the subring test requires that the additive identity (not the multiplicative identtity) to be in A.

Comment: I think in your line before last in the last term the power of y is not correct... am I correct?

Comment: @Confusion, that is incorrect: the subring test requires that in order for a subset $S$ of a ring $R$ to be a sub*ring* of $R,$ the multiplicative identity of $R$ must be an element of $S.$ Further, if $S$ is closed under subtraction, then for every element $s$ of $S,$ we have that $0_R = s - s$ is in $S.$

Comment: @Confusion, good call about the last line. In fact, my first displayed equation was also incorrect.

Comment: According to Thomas W. Hungerford, abstract algebra, on pg.41, I think it is the first edition, we should show the additive identity is in the subring not the multiplicative identity .... but no problem may be they are equivalent tests.

Comment: you know what I really liked about your answer was the example of showing how 2 terms can be transformed into a monomial .... I do not see why you deleted it and not adjusted it.

Comment: Why your first displayed equation was wrong ? why your n has two indices?

Comment: @Confusion, like I have shown, if $S$ is closed under subtraction, then it contains the additive identity of $R,$ so there is no need to assume that. We are dealing with rings (not *rngs*), so we do need to assume that $S$ contains the multiplicative identity $1_R$ of $R.$

Comment: I deleted that portion of my answer because it is trivial. Originally, there was a fatal typo when I listed a typical element of $A$; if I had kept it, we would not have been talking about $A$ but some other object. Like mathcounterexamples.net has shown above, a monomial in $A$ is of the form $(xy^{i_1})^{j_n} \cdots (xy^{i_n})^{j_n},$ so a polynomial in $A$ is a $k$-linear combination of these. We need two indices on the powers: the first refers to the coefficient $c_j$; the second refers to how many monomial factors $\ell_j$ are in the monomial.